# JavaScript Form Validation works in Chrome/Firefox not IE/Edge

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am working on Form Validation using JavaScript.  It works in Firefox 52.7.3 and Chrome  65.0.3325.162, but I just realized it does not work in Internet Explorer 11 or Edge 38.14393.2068.0.  It did work in all browsers before I made a bunch of changes and I don't know where I went wrong.  In IE and Edge, it will still email the form, but it doesn't validate any errors.  I appreciate any help I can get, it's very frustrating to think I am finally making progress and almost done only to discover it doesn't work in all browsers.

Code:

```js
function validateForm() {

  var firstName = document.getElementById("fName").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lName").value;
  var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
  var zipCode = document.getElementById("zip").value;
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  var area = document.getElementById("areaCode").value;
  var phone = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
  var email1 = document.getElementById("email1").value;

  if (document.getElementById("fName").value == "First Name") {
    alert("Please enter your first name");
    return false;
  }

  if (!firstName.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
    alert("Please use only letters A - Z for first name");
    return false;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("lName").value == "Last Name") {
    alert("Please enter your last name");
    return false;
  }
  if (!lastName.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
    alert("Please use only letters A - Z for last name");
    return false;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("address").value === "") {
    alert("Please enter your address");
    return false;
  }
  if (!address.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i)) {
    alert("Please use only letters and numbers in address");
    return false;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("city").value === "") {
    alert("Please enter your city");
    return false;
  }
  if (!city.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
    alert("Please use only letters A - Z for city");
    return false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("state").value == "--Select--") {
    alert("Please select your state");
    return false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("zip").value === "") {
    alert("Please enter your zip code");
    return false;
  }
  if (isNaN(document.getElementById("zip").value)) {
    alert("Please enter only numbers for Zip Code");
    return false;
  }
  if (!zipCode.match(/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid 5 digit US zip code.");
    return false;
  }

  if (document.getElementById("areaCode").value === "") {
    alert("Please enter your area code");
    return false;
  }
  if (!area.match(/(^\d{3}$)|(^\d{3}-\d{2}$)/)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid 3 digit area code.");
    return false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value === "") {
    alert("Please enter your phone number");
    return false;
  }
  if (!phone.match(/(^\d{7}$)|(^\d{7}-\d{6}$)/)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid 7 digit phone number.");
    return false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("email1").value === "") {
    alert("Please enter your e-mail address");
    return false;
  }
  if (!email1.match(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/)) {
    alert("You have entered an invalid e-mail address");
    return false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("email2").value === "") {
    alert("Please confirm your email address");
    return false;
  }

  if (!email1.match(document.getElementById("email2").value)) {
    alert("Confermation email does not match");
    return false;
  }
  if (document.forms["myForm"]["mealPref"].value == "") {
    alert("Please choose a meal preference");
    return false;
  }

  if (document.forms["myForm"]["contMeth"].value === "") {
    alert("Please choose at least two contact methods");
    return false;
  }

}

function onBlur(el) {
  if (el.value === '') {
    el.value = el.defaultValue;
  }
}

function onFocus(el) {
  if (el.value == el.defaultValue) {
    el.value = '';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #E6E6FA;
  color: #6918B4;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

h1 {
  color: #6918B4;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5vw;
}

table {
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: left;
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

th {
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.areaCode {
  width: 8%;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.phoneNumber {
  width: 20%;
}

.zip {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>Registration Form</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myForm.css">
  <script src="js/form.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Registration Form</h1>

  <div id="content">

    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="mailto:SelkieFaery@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
      <br>
      <fieldset>

        *required fields<br>
        <br>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <br>
        <table class="center">
          <tr>
            <th>First Name:*</th>
            <th><input type="text" id="fName" value="First Name" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" name="firstName"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Last Name:*</th>
            <th><input type="text" id="lName" value="Last Name" onblur="onBlur(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)" name="lastName"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Address:*</th>
            <th><input type="text" id="address" name="address"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>City:*</th>
            <th><input type="text" id="city" name="city"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>State:*</th>
            <th>
              <select name="state" id="state">
                <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
                <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="California">California</option>
                <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
                <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
                <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
                <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
                <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
                <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
                <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
                <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
                <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
                <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
                <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
                <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
                <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
                <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
                <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="New York">New York</option>
                <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
                <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
                <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
                <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
                <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
                <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
                <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
                <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
                <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
              </select>
            </th>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <th>Zip code:*</th>
            <th><input type="text" id="zip" class="zip" name="zip"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Phone:*</th>
            <th><input type="text" id="areaCode" class="areaCode" name="areaCode">
              <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" class="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Email:*</th>
            <th><input type="text" id="email1" name="emailAddress"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Confirm Email:*</th>
            <th><input type="text" id="email2" name="confirmEmail"></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Meal Preference:*<br> (select one)</th>
            <th><input type="radio" name="mealPref" id="vegan" value="Vegan">
              <label for="vegan">Vegan</label><br>
              <input type="radio" name="mealPref" id="vegetarian" value="Vegetarian">
              <label for="vegetarian">Vegetarian</label><br>
              <input type="radio" name="mealPref" id="nonVeg" value="Non-Vegetarian">
              <label for="nonVeg">Non-Vegetarian</label><br></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Contact Method:*<br> (select more than one)</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="contMeth" id="phone" value="Phone">
              <label for="phone">Phone</label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="contMeth" id="email" value="E-Mail">
              <label for="email">E-Mail</label><br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="contMeth" id="mail" value="Mail">
              <label for="mail">Mail</label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="contMeth" id="linkedIn" value="LinkedIn">
              <label for="linkedIn">LinkedIn</label></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>Comments:</th>
            <th><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment"></textarea></th>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
        <br>
      </fieldset>
    </form>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would recommend getting yourself some VersionControl software such as Git, and learn to branch your project before making changes. In a case like yours, you could then revert back to a previous commit or branch to undo your changes. Also, do you know how to use the developer tools to step through your javascript code?

Comment: Why are you doing your own default placeholders instead of using the `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console when it doesn't work?

Comment: I tried the above snippet in IE11 and Edge 42 and it validated properly.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had deleted this minutes after posting it.  It turned out the error was not with the code, but with the computer I was working on.  Something was blocking the code from working properly.  I uploaded it to google drive and downloaded it again and it magically worked.  I was doing my own default placeholders because my JavaScript professor wants us to do it using JavaScript functions.  I'm still not exactly sure what the problem was, but it is fixed now.